# Adding a Tab in HTML

Tags: html

sorry for asking a basic question. I am interesting in adding a tab before a sublist item as follows:

```
<b>1. Hello</b>
nbsp;<li> Hi, This is Me </li>
```

However, nbsp; doesn't work in this case. Kindly advise.

Comment: `padding/margin`. Sounds like you want to learn CSS. Then you would not have this question.

Comment: Its `&nbsp;`, not `nbsp;` to insert a space character. If you want it to have margin, however, try setting a margin in CSS (which is way better and offers control on the amount of distance)

Comment: &nbsp; will work if you use it inside <pre> tag

Comment: @dfsq ... yes, i have to learn CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try to use CSS of this issues. CSS is always better way to modify design then design modification html tags.

So the solution for tab use CSS classes eg.:

```
<b>1. Hello</b>
<li class="tabulated"> Hi, This is Me </li>

<style>
.tabulated{
 padding-left:12px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `<b>` and `<li>` elements **cannot** be sibblings.

Comment: @Quentin ... any specific reasons for that?

Comment: A list contains list items and only list items. It would be nonsense to have something in a list that wasn't part of the list.